# How do I pass a password to hdiutil attach?

Tags: macos, time-machine, password

How do I pass a password to hdiutil attach?

I have an encrypted sparsebundle  (test.sparsebundle) and it's password is "test", with no quotes.

I'd like to automate opening that file.

I have tried

```
echo "test" | hdiutil attach -stdinpass test.sparsebundle
```

and

```
echo test | hdiutil attach -stdinpass test.sparsebundle
```

But it returns

hdiutil: attach failed - Authentication error

Answer (score 11):

Ah! A little more digging, and careful reading of the man page. I need a null terminated string.

So

```
printf '%s\0' 'test' | hdiutil attach test.sparsebundle -stdinpass
```

works.

Comment: If the password has no spaces or characters special to the shell it can be shortened to just: `printf test|hdiutil attach test.sparsebundle -stdinpass`

Comment: The `\0` isn't actually needed, but using `%s` is a good idea -- there are a lot of "special characters" that can trip you up.